# How to stuff bread puffs (Gougeres)

Tags: bread, cheese, batter, french-cuisine

The other day someone delighted me to a Stuffed [Gougere](http://www.google.ca/images?hl=en&safe=active&rlz=1C1GGLS_enCA366CA366&q=gougeres&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1440&bih=787). Mind you, I've made these delicacies at least 50 times, I've never figured out a way to stuff them without either ruining the crust, the puff, or without having puff-plosions.

The question is, how is it possible to stuff these darn things, with either wet, cheesey, or whole objects without sacrificing the puff or the crust

Answer (score 6):

Gougeres are not stuffed, at least in Bourgogne. The dough contain the cheese (Gruyere) and nothing is added to it after the fact. Well cooked gougeres have the cheese in the center still moist and gooey, giving the impression of an after the fact filling when in reality the cheese has been in the dough all along. If the inside of your gougere is dry, it's been in the oven for too long. Note that using anything else than gruyere, or eventually comté, is probably not going to get the gooey delicious result.

I guess the only way to add a filling would be to do it the same way you do profiteroles: simply slice the gougere horizontally with a sharp knife, add whatever you want inside, and put the top back in place.

Comment: Eric, I agree, and as I said, I've made them a lot; however, these things were definitely stuffed; Looking back at it, I think what they might've done, is that once they were out of the oven, did a cross shaped cut on the bottom of the puff, and pumped a savory custard with a very fine nozzle, and put a bit of butter to close over the gap and put it back in the oven for a minute or two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [syringe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syringe). But this won't work for objects like olives.